# How to Fix Nexus-4 sensor problem while on calls

Tags: nexus-4, proximity-sensor

I am having nexus 4 from my friends and I had a small issue with that.When i lift the call and place it my ear the screen was turning off when i remove from my ear then again it wont turn on please tellme which sensor will able to do that and I want to disable that sensor can any one tell me how to disable sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your Phone app, then tap the Menu/Overflow button and select the 'Settings' action. There should be an option to disable the sensor in those settings.

If there isn't, download the [Xposed Framework Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), open it up then select 'Framework' and 'Update/Install'. Reboot, then install the [Disable Proximity module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mrchandler.disableprox). Open up the Xposed Installer again, select Modules, check the box beside 'Disable Proximity' and reboot again.

Comment: You'll need to root your device first.  I did that with TowelRoot.  The module is now called Sensor Disabler.